# Acccessing a class from an external jar

Tags: java

I have searched for hours and I am not finding a solution, this is my last resort

I have a program that creates a data file via serialization, and the file is created successfully, and I can read the data (Deserialization) using the same program/ package.

The problem I have is that the data file must be read from another program and I have created the same class but I cannot read from the file (Class not found error) from a different program

```
//Class
public static class
{
   File inst_path = ....
}
```

So I created an external class so that I can create the data file from the same class and read using the same class. The class is saved as a jar file

How can I link both programs to the same class (External File)

**Edit**

Currently I am accessing my local these way

```
records.classes myclass = new records.classes()
myclass.inst_path = new File...
```

So I am looking for something that will look something like ...

```
externaljar.jar.classes myclass = new ...
```

I know this won't work but I need something like it.

Answer (score 0):

You just need the jar to be in the classpath of the two programs. Then you use the class as any other class: by importing it and using its name:

```
java -cp jarWithCommonSerializedClass.jar;jarWithTheProgramClasses.jar the.program.MainClass
```

Note: this is for Windows. Under *nix, `:` must be used instead of `;`.

See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html.

Also, respect the Java naming conventions. Java classes start with an upper-case letter. Variables never contain underscores and are camelCased.

Comment: Thanks, I took the easy or lazy way out, I imported the jar class via netbeans, and it is working, I wanted to do it  programmatically although I had no clue where to start. I will look at your script in more detail.